# PyGame animated sprite facing left problems

Tags: animation, sprite, pygame

I am having problems with the following piece of code:

```
def handle_image_flip(self, old_rect):
    new_rect = self.last_frame.get_rect()
    self.owner.rect = new_rect
    self.owner.rect.y = old_rect.y
    if self.owner.facing == -1:
        self.owner.rect.right = old_rect.right
    else:
        self.owner.rect.x = old_rect.x

def animate(self, tick):
    if tick - self.last_update > self.image_info[self.action]["frame_rate"]:
        self.last_frame = self.get_next_frame(tick)
        old_rect = self.owner.rect.copy()
        self.owner.image = self.last_frame
        self.handle_image_flip(old_rect)
        self.last_update = tick
```

Where:

```
self.owner is the sprite this piece of code handles
self.owner.facing is the direction the sprite is facing
self.last_frame is the new image I want to display
```

Since the **sprites have different widths**, I am getting glitchy animations when facing
LEFT (-1).

There are no problems when moving RIGHT whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you track player's location using `Rect.center` or `Rect.centerx` vs default of `topleft` then different widths can work.

Depending on your game, using sprite sheets may be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

in your `if` statement, in one case you change `self.owner.rect.right`, in the other case you change `self.owner.rect.x`.

This could be part of the problem since when you are moving left, you are changing `.right` rather than `.x`